# How can I filter on multiple criteria simultaneously?

Tags: r

I need to exclude any instance of six values from a dataset that I have and wonder if there is an "all-in-one" solution to achieve this.

Aside from the usual

```
df[df$val != "one" || df$val != "two", ]
```

approach, is there an easier way to achieve this when there are a larger number of criteria?

I have tried

```
combi %>%
  filter(siteLocation != c("", "VC2", "LB", "GHNA", "GH", "GA"))
```

and

```
combi %>%
  filter(siteLocation != "" | "VC2" | "LB" | "GHNA" | "GH" | "GA")
```

but neither work (you get the idea).

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` with `!` i.e. create a logical vector on a vector of elements on the `rhs` of `%in%`, and negate (`!`)

```
library(dplyr)
combi %>%
   filter(! siteLocation %in% c("", "VC2", "LB", "GHNA", "GH", "GA"))
```

---

NOTE: Using `!=` or `==` results in incorrect output as these are  elementwise comparisons i.e it checks the first element of 'siteLocation' not equal to `""`, then 2nd element with 'VC2' and so on until it reaches the last element of the vector.  Then, it does a recycling starting from `""`...